# Howto create generic type for generic function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function F:

```
function f<T>(a: T): T {
  return a;
}

// typeof f: <T>(a: T) => T
// let's give it an alias
type FunctionWithGenericParameter = <T>(a: T) => T;
```

this function is assignable to generic type `F`, with a concrete type argument:

```
type F<T> = (a: T) => T;
const f1: F<string> = f;
```

However, the type `FunctionWithGenericParameter` itself is not generic.

```
type FunctionWithStringParameter = FunctionWithGenericParameter<string>;
// TS2315: Type 'FunctionWithGenericParameter' is not generic.
```

My question is: can I somehow transform type of function f `<T>(a: T) => T` to type `(a: T) => T`, and thus generate type `F<T>`?

Comment: Do you mean `type FunctionWithGenericParameter<T> = (a: T) => T;`?

Comment: @AlekseyL. I mean via type mapping, not manually. Something that works in general case. You just gave another name to my type `F`, and not generated it from FunctionWithGenericParameter

Comment: Oh, sorry missed the `type F<T> ... ` part somehow